# Loop through a gallery in power apps

Tags: powerapps

I have a list of barcodes in SharePoint “barcodeList” and in powerapps have a barcode control and a gallery to store the captured barcodes and a button.

When the button clicked, i want to to patch the captured barcodes from the gallery into the barcodeList that they aren’t exist in the barcodeList!

Can you help me?

Thanks